# java.time.LocalDate and Wicket 7 DateTextField

Tags: date, java-8, wicket

I'm trying to connect a Wicket component `DateTextField` with a property of type `java.time.LocalDate`.

Following the hints in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39164369/1988304), I've tried to implement a custom `CompoundPropertyModel` which contains a `java.time.Localdate` property. I'm using Wicket 7.6 and JDK 8.

I'm new to Wicket and Java generics.

This is my code:

**Class LocaldateModel**

```
import java.time.*;
import java.util.Date;
import org.apache.wicket.model.IModel;

public class LocalDateModel implements IModel<Date>
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7262517323706786573L;
    private IModel<LocalDate> localDateModel;

    public LocalDateModel(IModel<LocalDate> localDateModel)
    {
        this.localDateModel = localDateModel;
    }

    @Override
    public Date getObject()
    {
        return Date.from(localDateModel.getObject().atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
    }

    @Override
    public void setObject(Date object)
    {
        localDateModel.setObject(
                Instant.ofEpochMilli(object.getTime()).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate());
    }

    @Override
    public void detach()
    {
        localDateModel.detach();
    }
}
```

**Class LocalDateModelButAlsoWrapping**

```java
import java.time.Localdate;
import java.util.Date;

public class LocalDateModelButAlsoWrapping<T> extends LocalDateModel implements IWrapModel<Date>
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8539316259078354206L;

    private IModel<Date> dateModel;

    public LocalDateModelButAlsoWrapping(IModel<LocalDate> localDateModel)
    {
        super(localDateModel);
        LocalDate localDate=localDateModel.getObject();
        dateModel.setObject(Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()));
    }

    @Override
    public IModel<Date> getWrappedModel()
    {
        return dateModel;
    }

    @Override
    public void setObject(Date object)
    {
       dateModel.setObject(object);
    }
}
```

**Class MyLocalDateCompoundPropertyModel**

```java
import java.time.Localdate;
import org.apache.wicket.Component;
import org.apache.wicket.model.*;

public class MyLocalDateCompoundPropertyModel<T> extends CompoundPropertyModel<T>
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7112056989820105247L;

    public MyLocalDateCompoundPropertyModel(IModel<T> model)
    {
        super(model);
    }

    public MyLocalDateCompoundPropertyModel(T object)
    {
        super(object);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> IWrapModel<T> wrapOnInheritance(Component component)
    {
        IWrapModel<T> actualModel;
        actualModel = super.wrapOnInheritance(component);

        if (actualModel.getObject() instanceof LocalDate)
        {
            return new LocalDateModelButAlsoWrapping(actualModel);
        }
        else
        {
            return actualModel;
        }
    }
}
```

**Class  with LocalDate property**

```java
import java.time.Localdate;

public class CustomerUI implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4071467669346190367L;

    private CustomerDTO customer;

    public LocalDate getActiveUntil()
    {
        return customer.getActiveUntil();
    }

    public void setActiveUntil(LocalDate activeUntil)
    {
        customer.setActiveUntil(activeUntil);
    }

    // more delegating getters and setters
}
```

**Creating the component**

```java
    detailsDialog = new MyCustomerDetailsDialog("createDialog",
            new MyLocalDateCompoundPropertyModel<CustomerUI>(Model.of(new CustomerUI())))
```

These are the error messages:

> Last cause: Property could not be resolved for class: class
>   example.ui.customer.CustomerUI expression: dialog WicketMessage:
>   Can't instantiate page using constructor 'public
>   example.ui.customer.MyCustomerOverviewPage()'. An exception has
>   been thrown during construction!

Stacktrace:

```
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Property could not be resolved for class: class example.ui.customer.CustomerUI expression: dialog
     at org.apache.wicket.core.util.lang.PropertyResolver.getGetAndSet(PropertyResolver.java:393)
     at org.apache.wicket.core.util.lang.PropertyResolver.getObjectWithGetAndSet(PropertyResolver.java:355)
     at org.apache.wicket.core.util.lang.PropertyResolver.getObjectWithGetAndSet(PropertyResolver.java:261)
     at org.apache.wicket.core.util.lang.PropertyResolver.getValue(PropertyResolver.java:111)
     at org.apache.wicket.model.AbstractPropertyModel.getObject(AbstractPropertyModel.java:86)
     at example.ui.models.MyLocalDateCompoundPropertyModel.wrapOnInheritance(MyLocalDateCompoundPropertyModel.java:35)
     at org.apache.wicket.Component.initModel(Component.java:3841)
     at org.apache.wicket.Component.getDefaultModel(Component.java:1625)
     at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer$2.component(MarkupContainer.java:876)
     at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer$2.component(MarkupContainer.java:872)
     at org.apache.wicket.util.visit.Visits.visitChildren(Visits.java:144)
     at org.apache.wicket.util.visit.Visits.visitChildren(Visits.java:123)
     at org.apache.wicket.util.visit.Visits.visitChildren(Visits.java:192)
     at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.visitChildren(MarkupContainer.java:983)
     at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.setDefaultModel(MarkupContainer.java:871)
     at example.ui.customer.MyCustomerDetailsDialog.<init>(MyCustomerDetailsDialog.java:44)
     at example.ui.customer.MyCustomerOverviewPage$2.<init>(MyCustomerOverviewPage.java:95)
```

Line 35 is:

```
 if (actualModel.getObject() instanceof LocalDate)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Updated, more succint answer

My original answer went way beyond what your actual problem was, but I didn't quite realise until afterwards. Here's a more succint version, but I'll keep the original around at the bottom.

The issue you're having is because the naive extension I suggested has one critical flaw.

`CompoundPropertyModel` will try to instantiate a model for **any** child component that does not have a model. When you use regular `CompoundPropertyModel` this is not an issue; where the model is irrelevant, its object is never attempted to be obtained.

What's happening here is that this extension of the model will not only create a model for any model-less child, but will also try to evaluate it for the sake of checking what the type of the property is.

The problem with that is, that you might have children components (e.g. links) where a model will not necessarily be resolved to anything. In this specific instance you seem to have added a component whose ID is "dialog"; even though it might not necessarily need a model, `CompoundPropertyModel` will still be invoked for it, and it'll try to get a property by the name of "dialog" from the underlying `CustomerUI` object.

So in order to not encounter this issue you need to prevent your extension from evaluating the model every time. Something simple like

```
@Override
public <T> IWrapModel<T> wrapOnInheritance(Component component)
{
    IWrapModel<T> actualModel;
    actualModel = super.wrapOnInheritance(component);

    if (component instanceof DateTextField && actualModel.getObject() instanceof LocalDate)
    {
        return new LocalDateModelButAlsoWrapping(actualModel);
    }
    else
    {
        return actualModel;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

---

### Original answer

To understand why your code is not working, you need to understand how `CompoundPropertyModel` works.

I'll use a slightly modified code snippet of yours to illustrate this

```
IModel<CustomerUI> customerUIModel = Model.of(new CustomerUI());
detailsDialog = new MyCustomerDetailsDialog("createDialog", new CompoundPropertyModel<CustomerUI>(customerUIModel));
```

Let's imagine we want to add a label to the `detailsDialog` that displays the "activeDate" property of the CustomerUI. If we were **not** using a `CompoundPropertyModel`, then in order to achieve that we'd have to do something like the following:

```
IModel<LocalDate> activeDateModel = PropertyModel(customerUIModel, "activeUntil");
detailsDialog.add(new Label("dialog", activeDateModel));
```

What `CompoundPropertyModel` does is lets us bypass providing a model to the component and doing simply

```
detailsDialog.add(new Label("activeDate"))
```

Then when the page is being rendered, a component will detect that it has no model and so it gives the parent models a chance to provide a model to it.

This is where `CompoundPropertyModel` would kick in. It looks at what component is requesting to have a model provided and does exactly that. However, how does it do that? Well, quite simply it does

```
return new PropertyModel(innerModel, component.getId())
```

And so because of this simple piece of logic you can bypass instantiating your own models on the children components, and have the models provided to them by the parent's `CompoundPropertyModel`. **However the ID of the child component must be referring to some property of the model object that is stored in the CompoundPropertyModel**. Otherwise you will get the exact error you're getting:

```
Property could not be resolved for class: class example.ui.customer.CustomerUI expression: dialog
```

Now let's look at your extension of the CompoundPropertyModel. When a component requests to get a model for itself, your extension does the following:

```
@Override
public <T> IWrapModel<T> wrapOnInheritance(Component component)
{
    IWrapModel<T> actualModel;
    actualModel = super.wrapOnInheritance(component);

    if (actualModel.getObject() instanceof LocalDate)
    {
        return new LocalDateModelButAlsoWrapping(actualModel);
    }
    else
    {
        return actualModel;
    }
}
```

What it does it invokes the default behavior of the `CompoundPropertyModel` to instantiate a model for a component, and then it detects whether this model returns an instance of a `LocalDate` and wraps that model in order to have a model that returns `Date` instead.

Because your extension still relies on the default behavior of `CompoundPropertyModel`, it will still use the component's wicket ID to determine what the name of the property within the inner model is. And so what's happening is this:

1. You added a component to your `detailsDialog` whose wicket ID is
   "dialog"
2. On line `actualModel = super.wrapOnInheritance(component);`
   your extension creates a `PropertyModel` to referring to your
   `CustomerUI` model and its property "dialog" (as that's the ID of
   the component provided)
3. On line `if (actualModel.getObject()
   instanceof LocalDate)` you attempt to get the value of this model.
   However, no property "dialog" exists on the `CustomerUI` object and
   so the error is thrown

So in the end you've done everything right. The only problem is that you added a child component whose wicket ID did not refer to a valid property.

Which also showcases a problem. The implementation I provided is naive. Whenever a component is added that does not have a model, this extended model will create a model for it but also **it will always try to get its value**. So if you add a child component which isn't even supposed to have a model, the compound property model will kick in even for those components.

So the more permanent solution would be something that does not involve trying to get the value of the model. E.g. you could check if the component is a `DateTextField`:

```
@Override
public <T> IWrapModel<T> wrapOnInheritance(Component component)
{
    IWrapModel<T> actualModel;
    actualModel = super.wrapOnInheritance(component);

    if (component instanceof DateTextField && actualModel.getObject() instanceof LocalDate)
    {
        return new LocalDateModelButAlsoWrapping(actualModel);
    }
    else
    {
        return actualModel;
    }
}
```

This would defer looking at the model until after you established that the component whose model you're trying to instantiate really does need a LocalDate model.

Comment: This answer is really way longer than it needs to be. I'll try to trim it a little.

Comment: Thanks a lot :-) I'll give feedback tomorrow.

Comment: is it possible to avoid the warnings related to type parameters ?

Comment: What's the warning? Passing actualModel to the wrapping constructor?

Comment: I've inserted the warnings as comments in my own answer (which is based on yours) in the class `MyLocalDateCompoundPropertymodel`

Comment: Is Wicket going to (or already have?) introduce a native date picker for LocalDate?

Comment: Not sure about that, but you could probably leverage Wicket 8's [Lambda Models](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/8.x/single.html#_imodel_and_lambda) to do model wrapping quite easily

Answer (score 0):

Based on WiseTrees answer, I modified my classes. This solution works, although there are warnings related to type casting in the class `MyLocalDateCompoundPropertyModel`.

**class MyLocalDateModel**

```java
package example.ui.models;

import java.time.*;
import java.util.Date;
import org.apache.wicket.model.IModel;
import example.misc.MyDateTimeUtil;

public class MyLocalDateModel implements IModel<Date>
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7262517323706786573L;
    private IModel<LocalDate> localDateModel;

    public MyLocalDateModel(IModel<LocalDate> localDateModel)
    {
        this.localDateModel = localDateModel;
    }

    @Override
    public Date getObject()
    {
        return MyDateTimeUtil.createDateFromLocalDate(localDateModel.getObject());
    }

    @Override
    public void setObject(Date object)
    {
        localDateModel.setObject(MyDateTimeUtil.createLocalDateFromDate(object));
    }

    @Override
    public void detach()
    {
        localDateModel.detach();
    }
}
```

**class MyWrappingLocalDateModel**

```java
package example.ui.models;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Date;
import org.apache.wicket.model.*;

public class MyWrappingLocalDateModel extends MyLocalDateModel implements IWrapModel<Date>
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8539316259078354206L;

    public MyWrappingLocalDateModel(IModel<LocalDate> localDateModel)
    {
        super(localDateModel);
    }

    @Override
    public IModel<Date> getWrappedModel()
    {
        return Model.of(super.getObject());
    }

    @Override
    public void setObject(Date object)
    {
       super.setObject(object);
    }
}
```

**class MyLocalDateCompoundPropertyModel**

```java
package example.ui.models;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import org.apache.wicket.Component;
import org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.form.DateTextField;
import org.apache.wicket.model.*;

public class MyLocalDateCompoundPropertyModel<T> extends CompoundPropertyModel<T>
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7112056989820105247L;

    public MyLocalDateCompoundPropertyModel(IModel<T> model)
    {
        super(model);
    }

    public MyLocalDateCompoundPropertyModel(T object)
    {
        super(object);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> IWrapModel<T> wrapOnInheritance(Component component)
    // warning: type Parameter 'T' hides type parameter 'T'
    {
        IWrapModel<T> actualModel;
        actualModel = super.wrapOnInheritance(component);

        if ((component instanceof DateTextField) && (actualModel.getObject() instanceof LocalDate))
        {
            return (IWrapModel<T>) new MyWrappingLocalDateModel((IModel<LocalDate>) actualModel);
            // warning: unchecked cast
        }
        else
        {
            return actualModel;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `// warning: type Parameter 'T' hides type parameter 'T'` refers to that both the generic variable of your class and the generic variable of your method are called T, hence the generic of your method is hiding the generic of the class. As for the other warning, there's no way around not casting `actualModel`, but you have the if statement guarding it so it should be fine. And I don't think you can circumvent the last cast either.